# Can I assign multiple values to the appliedCharacterStyle property of InDesign DOM's Text object?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am working on an ExtendScript script which we use to prepare InDesign files for export to XHTML. Basically, we just go around applying character styles where we need them (have a look at this simplified example):

```
app.activeDocument.findGrep()[0].appliedCharacterStyle = "customStyle";
```

When we export the result to XHTML using InDesign's *Export to XHTML* feature, we get something like this:

```
<span class="customStyle">I</span>
```

which is exactly what we want. The problem arising now is that we sometimes want to apply many different styles to a single character, so we end up doing something like this:

```
var t = app.activeDocument.findGrep()[0];
t.appliedCharacterStyle = "customStyle1";
t.appliedCharacterStyle = "customStyle2";
```

Obviously, `customStyle2` overrides `customStyle1`, which defeats the purpose. Is there any way around this?

**Note:** I tried using `applyCharacterStyle` instead, but that method doesn't take strings as parameter, only [CharacterStyle](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5.5js_html/idcs5.5js/pc_CharacterStyle.html) objects.

Answer (score 1):

Is "customStyle" just a css class or the name of a saved style? I don't really use inDesign so this is speculation but it looks like you could modify individual properties of the CharacterStyle object like

```
var myStyle = new CharacterStyle();
myStyle.fillColor = "blue";
myStyle.fontStyle = "verdana";
...
```

Or something then you should be able to apply it like this

```
t.applyCharacterStyle(myStyle);
```

This is just an educated guess based on my experience with extendscript and photoshop, Sorry if it's way off-base.

Comment: You're right, `applyCharacterStyle` accepts `CharacterStyle` objects which have all sorts of attributes, including `fillColor`, `fontStyle`, etc. But it can also receive a `String` which eventually becomes a css class. This second option is what I need in my case. Indeed, it makes more sence to change a stylesheet when we want to modify a font color, for example, than to modify the script which extracts text from InDesign documents...